# Unity via tightvnc on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, 13.04, vnc

I can not seem to get unity to run and be accessible via VNC, all I get is the ubuntu desktop wallpaper, and mouse etc. 
But no Unity launcher or top bar.

Currently using the default xstartup to get that result.

Also tried the set up found here [tightvncserver on ubuntu 12.04 server with ubuntu-desktop installed no unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130110/tightvncserver-on-ubuntu-12-04-server-with-ubuntu-desktop-installed-no-unity) But that does not work as ubuntu-2d no longer used.

What Xstartup settings would I need to use to get unity working right? I would rather stick to using tightvnc as the vnc server as there is no physical screen.

Answer (score 1):

I've never managed to get unity working on my Ubuntu 13.04. Try launching 
gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback

, you're right in that ubuntu-2d is no longer there; it was removed in 12.10.